# Remove and replace printed words in same command line

Tags: python, string, format

I want to write a function where user gives the file name and sets a "speed" parameter to display words at a desired speed. The function then starts printing word by word in the file but replacing the previous one on the same command line.

This is my function:

```
def quick_reader(a):
    fhandle = open(a)
    document = fhandle
    for line in document:
        words = line.split()
        for i in range(0,len(words)):
            print("> " + words[i], end="\r")
            time.sleep(1)
```

Problem is that by the third word it starts adding extra letters to some words and messes it up. It does print on the same line and replacing the previous word, it just messes the words.

Answer (score 0):

It messes up because you need to "erase" the overshooting characters from the previous `print`.

One way of doing this is by storing the length of the previous line then printing as many spaces at the next iteration, before printing the next line.

```
def quick_reader(a, prefix="> ", delay=1):
    lgth = 0
    pref_length = len(prefix)
    with open(a) as fhandle:
        document = fhandle
        line = fhandle.readline()
        while line:
            # Strip() after the while check,
            # so it doesn't exit the loop with an empty line.
            line = line.strip()
            # Erasing the line
            print(" " * lgth , end="\r")
            # Printing the new line
            print(prefix + line, end="\r")
            # Storing the current line's length
            lgth  = len(line) + pref_length
            time.sleep(delay)
            line = fhandle.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

My earlier (now deleted) comment was incorrect, outputting backspaces won't erase the characters. Instead you will need to overwrite the line with blanks to get rid of them:

```
import time

def quick_reader(filepath, delay=1):
    with open(filepath) as file:
        for line in file:
            for word in line.split():
                print('>', word, end='', flush=True)
                time.sleep(delay)
                print('\r ', ' ' * len(word),  end='\r', flush=True)
    print()
```